# Prove a language in not in coNP

Tags: complexity-theory, np

Can someone tell me how to prove a particular problem/language does not belong to coNP?

Intuitively, we should show that the complement of the problem is not in NP, but I am not sure this is the way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is quite difficult. For example, right now we know that

> **P** ⊆ **NP** ⊆ **PSPACE** ⊆ **EXPTIME**

but don't know whether any individual one of those "subset of" relationships are strict. This means that no one knows of a problem in **EXPTIME** or **PSPACE**, for example, that is not in **NP**. As a result, even problems that we strongly suspect are not in **NP**, such as [TBQF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula), as of now can't be proven not to be in **NP**.